Evaluate if Internet Connectivity is UP using Ping Command in Bash

I want to evaluate if Internet Connectivity is up using bash
So, I am pinging to a random website to test connectivity
If it is up, do action 1.
If it is down, do action 2.

I have written the following
    if ping -q -w 1 -c 1 https://www.example.com > /dev/null
    then
            echo "Internet is up"

    else
            echo "Internet is down"

Also, it would be great if you could suggest me a way to do the same using curl/grep

Whether a web server is pingable or not has nothing to do with whether the website is accessible with the browser. Two completely different protocols are used here.

Modified. Thanks. I was trying to look for a solution to check if internet is up or not. Therefore, I tried to initiate a ping request to a random website. Hope that clarifies. @Cyrus

"The Internet" is always up. Do you mean to test if your network connection on the machine is up?  Do you want to test if a particular machine is reachable from your machine?

@StephenP Yes, exactly. Basically, test is internet connectivity on my machine is up

Use ping -q -w 1 -c 1 8.8.8.8

The argument to ping must be a hostname or address, not a URL.

Please [edit] your question to tell us what you mean by "the same using curl/grep". You can run curl on a URL just like you can run ping on one so it's not clear why you wouldn't already know how to do that (or be able to google it), and then it's not at all clear what you'd want to do with grep.

Are you trying to test if your machine can reach ANY internet host (i.e. "internet" is working on your local machine) rather than whether or not it can reach a specific internet host (i.e. "internet" is working on that remote machine and your local machine can reach it)?

Use nc utility for that, smth like
    # Let's set connection timeout to 1 sec
    if nc -zw1 $hostname $port >/dev/null 2>&1
    then
        echo "'$hostname:$port' is reachable!"
    fi

